# Unable to connect to DB in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

php artisan migrate works, but
I can migrate, but when I try to retrieve a record with eloquent, I get the following error
The environment is docker.

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433? (SQL: select * from "reservaions")
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=root
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  # PostgreSQL
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: myapp-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

controller

```
 public function getReservations()
    {
        $reservations = Reservaion::all();
        return $reservations;
    }
```

model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reservaion extends Model
{
}
```

The strange thing is that the DB client tools and migrations have been successful.
Why does it fail when accessing the DB from the controller via the model?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In docker-compose you can reach services by their names. Than, in your case,
`DB_HOST=db`

Why work?

Because you have Postgres installed on you computer (not docker) and when you migrate from console - your DB host can connect to 127.0.0.1

For future - work with artisan from docker php service:
`docker-compose exec {PHP_SERVICE} bash`

Comment: oh sorry, edited - host is not `pgsql`, it's `db`, copy paste is evil :)

Comment: Thank you.
I solved the problem by writing the container name of docker-db in .env.

Comment: Yes, service name OR container name